# Unable to block contacts whose numbers do not start with" +91" in call blocker android app

Tags: java, android

This application works perfectly with the contacts whose numbers are saved with +91,bt fails for other numbers.How do I solve this problem? And how do I add the options for adding numbers manually and from log ?

```
public class DeviceStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    private ITelephony telephonyService;
    private Context context;

    public DeviceStateListener(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        initializeTelephonyService();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private void initializeTelephonyService()
    {
        try
        {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Class clase = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Method method = clase.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            telephonyService = (ITelephony)method.invoke(telephonyManager);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, final String incomingNumber) 
    {
        switch(state)
        {

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                final BlockedContact cn = CallBlockerService.blackList.get(incomingNumber);
                if (cn != null && cn.isBlockedForCalling())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        telephonyService.endCall();
                        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss");
                                Date date=new Date();
                                String currentDate=dateFormat.format(date);

                                //LOG FORMAT --> TITLE;;MESSAGE;;NAME;;NUMBER;;HOUR;;BODYMESSAGE(NULL);;SEPARATOR
                                String message="Call Blocked;;A call from "+cn.getName()+" ("+incomingNumber+") was blocked at "+currentDate+";;"+cn.getName()+";;"+incomingNumber+";;"+currentDate+";;NULL;;\r\n";
                        writeInLog(message);
                            }
                        });
                        t.start();
                    } 
                    catch (RemoteException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
    }

    public void writeInLog(String message)
    {
        try
        {
            OutputStreamWriter fos = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("CallLog.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
            fos.append(message);
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("Written in log succesfully");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

}

Here is the BlockedContact class

```
public class BlockedContact implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7304477898143785497L;
    private String name;
    private String number;
    private int numberType;
    private boolean blockedForCalling;
    private boolean blockedForMessages;

    public BlockedContact(String name, String number, int numberType, boolean blockedForCalling, boolean blockedForMessages)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.number=number;
        this.numberType=numberType;
        this.blockedForCalling=blockedForCalling;
        this.blockedForMessages=blockedForMessages;
    }

    public boolean isBlockedForCalling() {
        return blockedForCalling;
    }

    public void setBlockedForCalling(boolean blockedForCalling) {
        this.blockedForCalling = blockedForCalling;
    }

    public boolean isBlockedForMessages() {
        return blockedForMessages;
    }

    public void setBlockedForMessages(boolean blockedForMessages) {
        this.blockedForMessages = blockedForMessages;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumberType() {
        return numberType;
    }

    public void setNumberType(int numberType) {
        this.numberType = numberType;
    }
```

}

Comment: The question would be much nicer if the code you posted was actually focused on the problem. Where do I find the pieces that deal with blocking `+91` but not without?

Comment: This is just a simple call blocker for android.What I was trying to say is that since the incoming number contains the prefix country code,it is not able to block those contacts whose numbers are not saved in contacts with the prefix.(+91 for India)

Comment: But isn't the user able to add the numbers he wants to block ? If so, that shouldn't be a problem if he can select it from its contacts list.

Comment: Yes,he can select a no. from contacts.
e.g.contact to b blocked has number 9876543210,and i receive call from that no as +919876543219.In this case,the app doesn't work.And if the contact has its no saved with prefix code,then it works

Comment: So if he selects for example `+33123456789` it will block this number even if it doesn't start with `+91` right ? I don't understand the problem..

Comment: The problem is that the incoming number should EXACTLY match with that of the blacklisted contact else the app wont block it.

Comment: @Flawyte Suppose u have saved a contact as 123456789 and added it to your blacklist.If u receive a call from that contact as +33123456789,it wont block.Works perfectly if the contact was saved with +31,

Comment: @SandeepNehra Did you search if there are equivalents to the country code that is used **inside** the country ? For example the country code for *France* is `33` but inside the french territory you can also use `0`. It means that `+33 1 23 45 67 89` is the same as `01 23 45 67 89`. So if the user selects `+33123456789` you also have to blacklist `0123456789`, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are Utility presented in android Read this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

You can use compare method to check number. it compare phone number

and also use other options according to your need. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you search if there are equivalents to the country code that is used **inside** the country ?

For example the country code for *France* is `33` but inside the french territory you can also use `0`. It means that `+33 1 23 45 67 89` is the same as `01 23 45 67 89`. So if the user selects `+33123456789` you also have to blacklist `0123456789`, and vice-versa.